# How do I replace characters in a list of strings with a different character?

Tags: python, list, replace

I am making a platformer with enemies and want to have enemies randomly placed on the map. My map contains lists of strings that specify the map tiles. Basically I just want to randomly put the letter 'E' on a random places in the list but only in areas that are empty.

My code:

```
import random

old_level_map = [
'6--------------------------------------------------------------------7',
'L                                                                    I',
'9____________________________________________________________________8',
'                                                                      ',
'                                                                      ',
'      P                                                               ',
'                                                                      ',
'                                                                      ',
'6--------------------------------------------------------------------7',
'L                                                                    I',
'9____________________________________________________________________8']

level_map = []
for j in old_level_map:
    line = list(j)
    for i in line:
        if str.isspace(i) == True:
            if random.random() < 0.1:
                new = i.replace(i, 'E')
                i = new
        print(i)
    level_map.append(line)
```

I might have went about this wrong. I went through each item in the list and then created individual lists out of those. Then I went through those lists and checked if there was an empty space, then there was a 10% chance of the item in the list being replaced by an 'E'. When I ran my code, no enemies showed up. So I printed 'i' and it showed that the letter 'E' was scattered throught. This means that 'i' doesn't correspond to my line list anymore. If someone could help that would be really helpful! I am a young programmer and this is my first time asking on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the character you replaced by `"E"` at all. You need to add it back to the list of characters. The simplest way to do that is to replace the item in the list at that index, and the index is provided by `enumerate`:

```
import random

old_level_map = [
'6--------------------------------------------------------------------7',
'L                                                                    I',
'9____________________________________________________________________8',
'                                                                      ',
'                                                                      ',
'      P                                                               ',
'                                                                      ',
'                                                                      ',
'6--------------------------------------------------------------------7',
'L                                                                    I',
'9____________________________________________________________________8']


level_map = []
for line in old_level_map:
    line = list(line)
    for n, char in enumerate(line):
        if char.isspace() and random.random() < 0.1:
            line[n] = "E"
    level_map.append("".join(line))
    
print(level_map)

['6--------------------------------------------------------------------7',
 'L         E E   EE              E                E         E   E     I',
 '9____________________________________________________________________8',
 'E                            E                   E  E   E E  E        ',
 '                            E  E                  E                   ',
 '      P  E     E     E E E   E E E             E         E         E  ',
 '       E                                E     E      EE   E          E',
 '     E        E            E     E                       E  E         ', 
 '6--------------------------------------------------------------------7', 
 'L          E E     E                 E             E                 I', 
 '9____________________________________________________________________8']
```

The same thing much shorter:

```
def randomly_replace(char: str) -> str:
    return "E" if char.isspace() and random.random() < 0.1 else char

level_map = ["".join(map(randomly_replace, line)) for line in old_level_map]
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was so quick and the code worked perfectly! I'm so happy right now, I was so mad because of this problem. I actually tried the '.join' method but I didn't use it correctly.

Comment: At the time I didn't require them to be equally spaced apart. This answer still doesn't work because there shouldn't be any enemies too close to each other.

Comment: @YasserMachkour Feel free to post a new question. The current answer works for the current question.

Comment: I did post a new question. I made a mistake by commenting here but I meant to comment on the new question I just posted. However no one has answered it and it has a downvote, so maybe I asked the question wrong. Basically I just want the same thing but the enemies should never be as close to each other as a set radius which is hard to execute in a linear list.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the base problem, which is spacing them apart by going through the list both ways.

```
import random

def adjust_numbers():
    enemies = []
    radius = 5
    enemy_count = 10
    space = 50
    for i in range(enemy_count):
        enemies.append(random.randint(0, space))

    sorted_numbers = sorted(enemies)
    print(sorted_numbers)
    adjusted_numbers = [sorted_numbers[0]]

    for i in range(1, len(sorted_numbers)):
        prev_adjusted = adjusted_numbers[-1]
        diff = sorted_numbers[i] - prev_adjusted

        if diff >= 5:
            adjusted_numbers.append(sorted_numbers[i])
        else:
            adjusted_numbers.append(prev_adjusted + radius)

    adjusted_numbers[len(adjusted_numbers) - 1] = 55
    print(adjusted_numbers)
    index = 0
    for i in adjusted_numbers:
        if i > space:
            adjusted_numbers[index] = space
        index += 1

    adjusted_numbers.reverse()
    sorted_numbers = adjusted_numbers
    adjusted_numbers = [sorted_numbers[0]]

    for i in range(1, len(sorted_numbers)):
        prev_adjusted = adjusted_numbers[-1]
        diff = sorted_numbers[i] - prev_adjusted

        if diff >= 5:
            adjusted_numbers.append(sorted_numbers[i])
        else:
            adjusted_numbers.append(prev_adjusted - radius)


    print(adjusted_numbers)

adjust_numbers()

[3, 6, 8, 8, 11, 22, 28, 30, 36, 44]
[3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 55]
[50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5]
```

As you can see the output is a perfect spread out version of the list, since there are 10 enemies and 50 spaces, and 50/10 = 5.

Comment: I'm going to try and apply this vertically and then apply it to my code.